# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jersey, jackson

I am getting this error after in my GAE log. I have googled it and I tried the following but they didn't solve the problem. I am using jackson 2.0 with jersey. I have tried updating my Jackson jars to the latest version but it didn't help.

1. Replacing all the jackson jars (core, databinding and annotation)
2. disabled DisableWADL in web.xml
3. including rome1.0.jar

Anyone else have any ideas?

```
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-3e0d19a979182c6d(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1277)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2447)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-3e0d19a979182c6d(Request.java)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: do u have `jettison <version>.jar` in your classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add jettison jar to your WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: do I need to add it to the build path as well or just the lib folder?

Comment: I would say you should handle the jettison jar in the same way you do with other jars (jackson, rome etc) in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, instead of adding Jettison jars, make sure you are NOT using Jettison-based data-binding -- it is not needed by POJO mapping, or by Jackson. So your dependency on it could be accidental, and adding jar will just mask the real problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about this, I'm suppose to be using Jackson but this keeps breaking the deployment, how do I make sure it is not set accidentally?

Thanks

Comment: @Frank This is rather ancient question. Original author was not using Jackson; stack trace shows org.json-package based provider. I don't know how that was configured, or should be; but (s)he was not using Jackson-based provider. Similarly I don't know what you are doing but you need to read Jersey documentation on how to select appropriate JSON provider.